# How to filter dataframe on index AND column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have 2 dataframes like this:

df1

```
             sales    day    ...
    index    
    1001     567      321
    1002     600      1530
    1005     789      998
    1008     825      775
    1002     300      1120
```

df2

```
             sales    day    ...
    index    
    1001     567      321
    1002     600      1530
    1005     789      998
    1014     620      1000
    1008     825      775
    1009     589      1100
    1002     300      1120
    1005     770      400
    1008     820      1600
```

and I want to keep only rows in df2 that the index and day values are exactly the same as df1

so result should be:

df2

```
             sales    day    ...
    index    
    1001     567      321
    1002     600      1530
    1005     789      998
    1008     825      775
    1002     300      1120
```

I cannot use the isin function as below because there are rows in df2 that have the same index but a different day value. It is the combination of index and day that is unique.

```
    df2 = df2[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

Essentially what I want to do in SQL would be

```
    select *
    from   table1 t1,
           table2 t2,
    where  t1.id = t2.id
    and    t1.day = t2.day;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append` parameter, so possible filtering by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df2[df2.set_index('day', append=True).index.isin(df1.set_index('day', append=True).index)]
print (df)
       sales   day
index             
1001     567   321
1002     600  1530
1005     789   998
1008     825   775
1002     300  1120
```

Alternative with `merge`:

```
df = (df1.reset_index()
         .merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['day','index'], suffixes=('_',''))
         .set_index('index')[df2.columns])
print (df)
       sales   day
index             
1001     567   321
1002     600  1530
1005     789   998
1008     825   775
1002     300  1120
```

Comment: It looks like that solution is working on the restricted dataframes I have included here but when applying to the full size dataframes (20k rows and 40k rows) it is not filtering all. I think it is because there are rows with the same 'day' value

Comment: @daragh - added alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to set a double index on both dataframes and use loc access:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().set_index(['index','day'])
df2 = df2.reset_index().set_index(['index','day'])

print(df2.loc[df1.index])
```

Output (you can do `reset_index(level=1)` if you don't want double index)

```
            sales
index day        
1001  321     567
1002  1530    600
1005  998     789
1008  775     825
1002  1120    300
```